# Ignoring case when writing to cassandra from spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a spark dataframe:

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(
  [
    (1,2),
    (3,4),
  ],
  ["Col1", "Col2"]
)
```

I created the equivalent table in cassandra:

```
CREATE table external.test1(
    Col1 int, 
    Col2 int, 
    primary key (Col1) 
) ;
```

Using the package [spark-cassandra-connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/), I try to insert my dataframe into my table:

```
df1.write.format(
  'org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra'
).options(
  keyspace='external',
  table='test1'
).save()
```

and received the error:

> java.util.NoSuchElementException: Columns not found in table
>   external.test1: Col1, Col2

I figured out that the error is due to a case mismatch between spark and Cassandra. Cassandra ignores the upper-case of my script and created the columns all lower-case. Spark keeps the upper-case in the column names.

Therefore, this code is executed without error:

```
df1.select(
    *(map(str.lower, df1.columns))
).write.format(
  'org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra'
).options(
  keyspace='external',
  table='test1'
).save()
```

How can I force Cassandra to accept my data ignoring the case? Or is there a simple way to convert all my columns to lower case (even within a struct, array of structs, ...)?

Comment: check table description.. cassandra will create columns in lowercase unless enclosed in double quotes..

Comment: @undefined_variable I am sorry but I don't really see your point. I know that cassandra will create the columns in lower case, I already said that in my post. What do you suggest? That I should create the column in Camel Case directly in cassandra ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spark Cassandra Connector always "quotes" the names of the tables, and columns, so either they should be created as "quoted" names in schema (in double quotes), or you need to use lower-case names in your data frame - it shouldn't be very hard to rename all columns of your data frame to lower case.

Answer (score 1):

If you want cassandra not to create column in lower case, please use double quotes for you column name in your create table query like mentioned below:

Create table tablename ("columnname" datatype);